# How to trigger program after Windows PC returns from hibernate mode

Tags: windows

Is there an event that is triggered when a Windows 7 computer has been restarted after being put into hibernate which I can use to run a program - very much the same way the task scheduler would to, just not time based in this case, but event based?

It'd be easy to accomplish after system start, but I haven't found anything similar for a "return from rest mode" scenario.

I need to start an exe in order to send an email notification every time this happens.

Comment: By "rest mode" do you mean suspend and/or hibernate?

Comment: @John Gardeniers: Hibernate. I'll correct that (my translation from German was too direct, apparently). However, knowing this for sleep mode would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just test a little program I wrote years ago and it does work on Windows 7. When run it places an icon in the system tray. Right click the icon and select Configure. The rest should be obvious. Download it [from here](http://www.gardeniers.com/files/HiberMon.exe). (It's freeware and therefore comes with no warranties of any sort.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I will test it asap. Can you point in the direction of the principle that has been used?

Comment: @Olaf, Windows sends what amounts to internal broadcast messages when certain events occur, such as when entering or exiting suspend or hibernate modes. My program simply waits for those message and then runs whatever you have configured for that event.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows XP this claims to do do what you need:

http://www.desimonesystems.com/suspendtrigger/index.php

Comment: The question very clearly states that it's a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: You're right - totally missed that!